# WCF modifying ReaderQuotas for HttpTransportBindingElement in CustomBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

The `BasicHttpBinding` class has a `ReaderQuotas` property that you can access to override attributes such as `MaxArrayLength`, `MaxBytesPerRead`, etc.

How can I access `ReaderQuotas` to achieve the same thing when using an `HttpTransportBindingElement` within a `CustomBinding` instead of `BasicHttpBinding`?

i.e.:

```
var bindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
bindingElement.MaxBufferSize = 65536; // works
bindingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 65536; // error no ReaderQuotas member

var binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElements);
binding .ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 65536; // also no ReaderQuotas member
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the message encoding binding element `TextMessageEncodingBindingElement` not `HttpTransportBindingElement`:

```
        var bindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        bindingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 65536;

        var binding = new CustomBinding();
        binding.Elements.Add(bindingElement);
```

The other [message encoder types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731802.aspx) (i.e. binary or MTOM) could be used but if you are doing straight conversion [the default for basicHttpBinding is text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.messageencoding.aspx):

> The value of WSMessageEncoding that indicates whether MTOM or Text/XML
>   is used to encode SOAP messages. The default value is Text.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the below:

```
var binding = new CustomBinding();
var myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 5242880;
binding.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding, myReaderQuotas, null);
```

Hope that helps.